# Mass of an ellipsoid with variable density

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, physics, multiple-integral

So I'm given the problem "An object fills the ellipsoid $x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 = 1$ and that its density is given by $r^2 \sin(\theta)$" and asked to solve for the mass.

Converting to Spherical I said it's $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{(1+\cos^2\theta)^{-1/2}} r^4 \sin^2\theta\, dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$$
The integral seems impossible to evaluate so I know I messed up somewhere but don't know where.

Comment: Use cylindrical coordinates. I assume that $r$ is the radius in 3D, and $\theta$ is the angle with respect to the $z$ axis

Comment: One way to make some progress is to let $u=\cos\theta$. Then the nontrivial integrals over $r,\theta$ become $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{1/\sqrt{1+u^2}} r^4 \sqrt{1-u^2}\,dr\,du$$ which is a bit easier to work with. (That said, the result I obtain from this approach seems to be expressed in terms of the gamma function. So I'm not sure this has been done correctly.)

Comment: Double-checking the above integral with Mathematica---including the cylindrical form---it seems that this is indeed the correct integral. The trouble is that the result is not expressible in elementary terms and requires use of special functions (either the gamma function values $\Gamma(1/4),\Gamma(3/4)$ or the complete elliptic integrals   $E(-1), K(-1)$). Depending on the course that may be fine, but if this is supposed to be an elementary integral then I'd recheck the problem.